# Can't declare foreign key in joomla 2.5

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__web_projects` 
(
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`type_website` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
`web_color` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
`web_fonts` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
`web_layout` text COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
`web_menu` text COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
`similar_web_sites` text COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
`additional_info` text COLLATE utf8_polish_ci,
`about_company` text COLLATE utf8_polish_ci,
`offer` text COLLATE utf8_polish_ci,
`logo` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `#__users`(id) ON DELETE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci
```

this is my declaration of table in joomla and i always get error that this table cant be created. What can cause that??

Comment: can you put shown error message on your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would like to mention that you should make you user_id UNSIGNED!**

I've tested your SQL in Joomla! 2.5 and it works flawless (I assuse anyway that your MySQL engine is InnoDB). Without a SQL error I am afraid nobody can help you.